# DS 160 form for non-immigrant visa application

Tags: visas, usa

I forgot to click on *family or group application* at the confirmation page of the DS 160 form in applying for my wife. If I start new application for her, will our date of interview be different or would it be the same?

Answer (score 1):

While it may differ at other US Embassies, here (Thailand) you choose your interview time from the available slots, so both of you could pick the same date & time with two slots available.  But you will likely be interviewed separately.